# Applying assumptions about marginal and conditional PDFs

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution

We are given $0 < x_2 < x_1 < 1$. What assumptions can you make about $f_1(x_1)$ and $f_{2|1}(x_2|x_1)$?

I know that $f(x_1) f_{2|1}(x_2|x_1) = \frac{1}{x_1}$. I know the expression can be expanded to $f_1(x_1) \frac{f(x_1,x_2)}{f_1(x_1)}$, which would lead me to believe that $f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{x_1}$. I just can't figure out why.

Comment: How do you know that $f(x_1)f(x_2|x_1) = 1/x_1$?

Comment: @jbowman It is given in an example in my (mathematical statistics) textbook. I'm trying to figure out how the author came to that conclusion, as they just assumed it without explanation.

Comment: well, isn't $f(x_1) f_{2|1}(x_2 | x_1) = f(x_1, x_2)$? isn't that just how the joint distribution is related to the conditional?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ken That's what I gather from both the book and the Internet. The question asks the reader to "Make assumptions about $f_1(x_1)$ and $f_{2|1}(x_2|x_1)$", given that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random variables where $0<x_2<x_1<1$. The problem is #2.3.11 from "Introduction to Mathematical Statistics" 7/8e, Hogg.

Answer (score 0):

This question needs re-interpretation and a cleaning up of the notation for it to make sense.  I am fairly sure that what the book means to say is

> Let $X$ and $Y$ denote continuous random variables that $0 < Y < X < 1$, $X \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$, and for each fixed real number $x$ such that $0 < x < 1$, $f_{Y\mid X=x}(y\mid X=x)$, the conditional pdf of $Y$ given that $X=x$, is a uniform density on $(0,x)$. That is, for fixed $x \in (0,1)$,
>   $$f_{Y\mid X=x}(y\mid X=x) = \begin{cases}\frac 1x, &0 < y < x,\\
> 0, &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}.$$
>   Since $$f_{X}(x) = \begin{cases} 1, &0 < x < 1,\\
> 0, &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases},$$
>   it follows that
>   $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{Y\mid X=x}(y\mid X=x)f_X(x) = \begin{cases}\frac 1x, &0 < y < x < 1,\\
> 0, &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}.$$